# show alert xcode and go back after alert

Tags: objective-c

i want to show the alert and when somebody click on OK they need to be send to the page before. How can i make this?

I use the following code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BOOYAH!" 
                                                message:@"Saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: What are you using to handle your 'pages'?

Comment: We will need more information about your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have 1 option on the alert view and the delegate is self.  Use this method in the same .m file as the code above

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertV didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //go back a page

    [alertV autorelease];

}
```

Don't forget to release the alert view. I added it in the delegate method, but you can choose to release it right after showing it (only 1 release though)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the UIAlertViewDelegate to self and then implement the following method is called

```
 - (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == buttonIndexForOK) { // Where buttonIndexForOK is the index for your ok button, in this case, that would be zero, but if you want an OK and a Cancel button this would be different.
          // go back to the last page
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` follows the delegation design pattern that is extremely common in iOS development.  You provide a delegate object, and when the object wants to tell you about something, it sends that delegate object a message.

In your code, you've provided `self` as the delegate.  This means that this object needs to conform to [the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html).

You will see that there are several methods you can implement to react to various events relating to the alert view.  You should use [the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView%3aclickedButtonAtIndex%3a), which provides an index parameter indicating which button was tapped.